# Flutter Unity Integration Communication Issue

Tags: flutter, dart, unity-game-engine, mobile-application, arcore

I am new to both flutter and unity and for learning purposes I integrated Unity AR module in flutter application. Now on button click flutter will send a message to unity to load the respective model in the scene. Both the flutter and unity modules are working fine but in communication, instead of loading the model after matching names, the application loads a static model which I used before integration. How to resolve this issue. Any help would matter a lot.

Here is my flutter code:

```
Expanded(
                child: UnityWidget(
                  onUnityCreated: (controller) {
                    _unityWidgetController = controller;
                  },
                ),
              ),
              // Button to send the model name
              ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
              String modelName = product;
              _unityWidgetController.postMessage(
                'ModelLoader', 'OnMessage', modelName);
              },
              child: Text('Load ${product}'),
              ),
```

and this is my unity code:

ModelLoader.cs script

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ModelLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject instantiatedModel;

    public void LoadModel(string modelName)
    {
    print(modelName);

    string modelPath = "Assets/Furniture/Prefabs/" + modelName;
        GameObject modelPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>(modelPath);

        if (modelPrefab != null)
        {
        // Destroy the previously loaded model, if any
            Destroy(instantiatedModel);
    Instantiate(modelPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load model: " + modelName);
        }
    }

    // Called when a message is received from Flutter
    public void OnMessage(string message)
    {
        print(message);
        // Parse the received message
        string modelName = message;

        string modelPath = "Assets/Furniture/Prefabs/" + modelName;
        GameObject modelPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>(modelPath);

        if (modelPrefab != null)
        {
        // Destroy the previously loaded model, if any
        Destroy(instantiatedModel);

        Instantiate(modelPrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to load model: " + modelName);
        }
    }
}
```

ARFocus.cs Script which takes ModelLoader script as a game object

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.XR;
using System;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ARFocusCircle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject virtual_object;
    public GameObject button;

    public GameObject placementIndicator;

    private ARSessionOrigin arOrigin;
    private Pose placementPose;
    private bool placementPoseIsValid = false;
    private bool isModelSpawned = false;
    private bool placementIndicatorEnabled = true;

    bool isUIHidden = false;

    private ARRaycastManager raycastManager;
    private ARPlaneManager planeManager;

   
    void Start()
    {
        raycastManager = FindObjectOfType<ARRaycastManager>();
        planeManager = FindObjectOfType<ARPlaneManager>();
        arOrigin = FindObjectOfType<ARSessionOrigin>();
        placementIndicator = Instantiate(placementIndicator, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
       
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (!isModelSpawned)
        {
            print("started");
            UpdatePlacementPose();
            print("placementpose updated");
            UpdatePlacementIndicator();
            print("placement indicator updated");

            if (placementPoseIsValid)
            {
                if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    print("Placing object");
                    PlaceObject();
                    placementIndicatorEnabled = false;
                    isModelSpawned = true;
                    placementPoseIsValid = false;
                }
                

            }
            
        }
    }

    public void HideUI()
    {

        if (isUIHidden == false)
        {
                button.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            placementIndicatorEnabled = false;
            placementIndicator.SetActive(false);

            isUIHidden = true;
        }

        else if (isUIHidden == true)
        {
                button.gameObject.SetActive(true);

            placementIndicatorEnabled = true;
            placementIndicator.SetActive(true);

            isUIHidden = false;

        }
    }

    public void PlaceObject()
    {

        string buttonName = EventSystem.current.currentSelectedGameObject.name;

        Instantiate(virtual_object, placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
            button.SetActive(false);
    }



    private void UpdatePlacementIndicator()
    {
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            print("entered update placement indicator true");
            placementIndicator.SetActive(true);
            button.SetActive(true);

            placementIndicator.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            print("entered update placement indicator false");
            placementIndicator.SetActive(false);
            button.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePlacementPose()
    {

        Vector3 screenCenter = new Vector3(Screen.width * 0.5f, Screen.height * 0.5f);
        var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
        raycastManager.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, TrackableType.PlaneWithinPolygon);

        placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            print("Placement pose is valid");
            placementPose = hits[0].pose;

            placementPose = hits[0].pose;
            print("Placement pose is valid");
            placementIndicator.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
            placementIndicator.SetActive(true);
        }
        else
        {
            placementIndicator.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to run the unity project separately and it does not load any static model. However when the integrated flutter application runs, it displays that model in scene.